# How to fetch a string from its first character in sqlitedb query

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a sqlitedb where it has table called symptomtable which contains ID (Integer)and SymptomName(String) as column . I have created a sqlite query where i am fetching SymptomName  based on the first letter of symptomName

for ex:- ..if first letter contains letter 'A' fetch those words , 'B' fetch those words and so on ..

Now i want to reverse the process from ID i want to fetch the symptonName based on first letter ...if a symptomName starts from letter 'D" i want to get list of items which starts from the letter 'D' in otherwords i want to fetch the list of SymptomName which consists of first letter from ID ..and return Indexpath

**In the query NSString *alphabetString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",i];  from this code i am getting character .**

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)indexReadData
{
    NSMutableDictionary *indexDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    int i;  
    NSString *dbPath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QuickCureNew1.sqlite"];
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &quickAppNew)==SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        for (i=65; i<=90; i++) 
        {
            NSString *alphabetString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",i];
            NSString *sqlStmtReadIndexSymptom=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Symptom where Symptom like '%@%%'",alphabetString];
            const char *sqlCharReadIndexSymptom=[sqlStmtReadIndexSymptom UTF8String];
            sqlite3_stmt *selectStmtReadIndexSymptom;
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(quickAppNew, sqlCharReadIndexSymptom, -1, &selectStmtReadIndexSymptom, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSMutableArray *indexArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                while (sqlite3_step(selectStmtReadIndexSymptom)==SQLITE_ROW) 
                {
                    indexIdNo=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(selectStmtReadIndexSymptom,0)];
                    symptomIndexTxt=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char*) sqlite3_column_text(selectStmtReadIndexSymptom, 1)];
                    symptomsIndexDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                       symptomIndexTxt,@"SymptIndexName",
                                       indexIdNo,@"SymptIndexID",nil];
                    [indexArray addObject:symptomsIndexDict];
                }
                if (indexArray.count>0) 
                {
                    [indexDict setObject:indexArray forKey:alphabetString];
                }
            }
        }
        sqlite3_close(quickAppNew);
    }
    return indexDict;    
}
```

Comment: why don't you get all records once in sorted form. And then group by starting letter ?

Comment: Tried `select * from Symptom where Symptom like '@%%'`? I don't know properly the syntax of the Obj-c query but % at start of the likes string `%@%%` allow other characters before your first letter.

Comment: araknoid ..thats my sqlite statment .

Comment: yunas ...When i enter a symptomName ...i need to fetch the first alphabet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `CoreData` it's a `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'a'"];
```

It's all in the Apple Developer reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html

Perhaps this points you in the right direction.